# arduino board to monitor two sepearated encoders

Tags: arduino, encoder

I have two linear quadrature encoders controlling two stepper motors. These two stepper motors move a stage (one in x, the other in y). There might be a feedback between the two motors but I am not sure. I would like to use interrupt on arduino to monitor the changes in channels A and B of each encoder. Should I get an arduino board (e.g. mega) with more than 4 interrupts, each interrupt can handle a distinct ISR?

Thank you,

Comment: Just a question: isn't a single ISR sufficient? Keep track of the previous state (like you should do for encoders) and then check it at every interrupt..

Comment: Because I would like to do bidirectional decoding (4x).

Comment: What do you mean by bidirectional decoding? You have four pins (two encoders, two pins each); you attach the ISR to the four-pins interrupt vector (for both raising and falling). Every time one of the pins is changed the ISR is fired; you compare the new values to the old ones and see what is the moving encoder and in which direction...

Comment: Does that mean I need 4 interrupt pins? The content of ISR will be the same for each pin but there should be 4 ISR parts in the code, each responds to a pin (channel)?

Comment: No, you can use the generic PCINT interrupt; for every enabled pin you receive a call to the associated ISR; you don't know what pin triggered the ISR, so you have to keep track of them (but you already had to keep track since you wanted to decode an encoder ;) )

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I would have one ISR for encoder 1 and one ISR for encoder 2, because the "count" for enconder 1 and the "count" for encoder 2 are different.

Comment: You can, because there are three interrupt vectors (PCINT0, PCINT1 and PCINT2, linked to Port B, C and D). But you can also write a single ISR and check both encoders at once. If it is possible for you then using two separate ISRs is easier...